# AngularJS - dynamic validation using $valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm using AngularJS to validate a form, and I have this button to submit.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="btn" ng-click="submit(settings.$valid)"
        class="btn btn-primary">
  Submit
</button>
```

This button is disabled whenever the form is invalid, but once it's valid, the button is enabled.

So this is my code

```
$http.get("http://localhost:5000/settings").then(function(response){
    $scope.numberOfRows = response.data.numberOfRows
    console.log($scope.numberOfRows)
    if($scope.numberOfRows==0 && $scope.settings.$valid == false ){
        $scope.btn=true
    }else if($scope.numberOfRows==0 && $scope.settings.$valid == true){
        $scope.btn=false
    }

    if($scope.numberOfRows==1){
        $scope.btn=true
    }

})
```

My problem is when the **numberOfRows** = 0 and the form is **invalid**, I can't submit the form which what I want.

**BUT**, when I fill my form and it became **valid**, nothings happend.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened? can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I mean, whenever i fill the form correctly, the button still disabled and I can't submit the form

Comment: You can debug this just do `{{btn}}` in the html, and do `console.log($scope.numberOfRows, $scope.settings.$valid)` inside the function you gave!

Comment: I tried {{btn}} but always true, and for the console.log(), it can't show you another result unless you refresh the page, it means you'll begin always at the same point

Comment: What you need to do, is give `ng-disabled="validate()"` for the button and move the if statements inside the validate function, this will calculate continuously, I think that your function is checking the conditions  only once.

Comment: Okaay I'll try it

Comment: You mean I create another function called validate () to verify if the form is valid or no. Because I have another function sumbit() which will submit the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153500/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-anes-el-gongi).

Answer (score 1):

```
$http.get("http://localhost:5000/settings").then(function(response){
    $scope.hasRow= response.data.numberOfRows>0;
    $scope.settings.$valid=$scope.hasRow;
})
```

and add this code to your html

```
 <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!settings.$valid" ng-click="submit()"
        class="btn btn-primary">
  Submit
</button>
```